# There is a bag which contains 10 red beads, 10 green beads and 12 yellow beads. How many ways can you pick a pile containing 22 beads?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, generating-functions

At first glance i thought to combine all 32 beads and just pick 22 from them because there's nothing saying you need a certain amount of a specific colour bead, or should I be looking at this question as each colour of bead is a generating function and then finding the coefficient for $[x^{22}]$

Comment: looks you want to solve $$r+g+y=22$$
$0\le r,g\le 10$ and $0\le y \le 12$

Comment: I expect the question wants you to take color into account. So choosing $12$ yellow and $10$ red is not the same as choosing $10$ each of red and green and $2$ yellow.  So your generating function approach is better.  Or you could do Inclusion-Exclusion.

Comment: Finding the coefficient of $x^{22}$ for the generating function $$(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{10})^2(1 + x + x^2 + \cdots + x^{12})$$ is one way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you have $0$ red beads, green+yellow $=22$, so there is only one way.  When you have $1$ red bead, green+yellow $=21$, so you  have  two ways,..., when you have $10$ red beads, green+yellow $=12$, so you have eleven ways.  Sum= $66$.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can case bash with 10 cases of red, which isn't terribly slow, complementary counting makes this way easier. You are trying to take 10 beads to *not* pick from a pile of 10 red, 10 green, and 12 yellow. This is essentially just a stars and bars problem with 10 stars and 2 bars (try to see if you can figure out what to use as your stars and bars), so the answer is 12C2, or 66 ways. Unless this is a specific exercise for generating functions, please do not use them as even the cases method is quite a bit faster.